# Copy one datatable to another datatable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have created a `datatable` which has some records, now what I want is to copy the record of first `datatable` to another `datatable`.

I tried like below:

```
Session["AmountData"] = AmountDatatable; // 1st datatable which has data

DataTable CompanyWiseRecord = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < AmountDatatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   CompanyWiseRecord.ImportRow(AmountDatatable.Rows[i]); // 2nd datatable which does not have data
}
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Documentation for ImportRow says the row will be ignored if its state is `Detached`. What are the states of the rows in `AmountDatatable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not fetching data from table one based on some condition or assign particular rows or columns then You can do it simply by using

```
DataTable CompanyWiseRecord=AmountDatatable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You directly use session Like:

`DataTable CompanyWiseRecord = (DataTable)Session["AmountData"]; //Retrieving DataTable from Session.`